# What could be causing my condensation dryer to have standing water under the heating exchanger?

Tags: dryer

Our zanussi zdc68560w condensation dryer leaks water from the heat exchanger. There is water in the water tank but also some is leaking from the front of the machine and sitting water under the heat exchanger. The black cardboard/plastic  underneath the machine is a bit bent near the right hand side. Is something blocked or another cause?

Answer (score 1):

Condenser dryers generate water, just like an air conditioner does. If water is leaking out, then either the water collection tank is full and overflowing, or the drain is clogged and overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the drain kit installed?  It is an option available from the appliance dealer.  See page 6 of [this](http://www.electrolux-ui.com/DocumentDownLoad.aspx?DocURL=2011%5C136%5C916130EN.pdf).

If not, you will have to manually empty the condensate (see [page 7](http://www.electrolux-ui.com/DocumentDownLoad.aspx?DocURL=2011%5C136%5C916130EN.pdf)).  The dryer has only a 4.3 litre capacity (see [page 55](http://www.zanussi.co.uk/LocalFiles/United_Kingdom_English/Brochures/FSBROCHURE2013.pdf)), probably not enough for more than 2 or 3 loads.

If the condensate tank is empty, then consider that a clothes dryer produces a lot of lint.  It is a fair bet that some lint or other debris has mixed with the drainage water to clog it.

Answer (score 0):

After two visits from the appliance engineer it turned out to be a combination of:

1. a stuck widget (?)that didn't stop the collection tank at the bottom back of the machine from overflowing and
2. the machine itself was not completely level. This is required so that the water is transported into the collection tank rather than to the front of the machine where it leaks out.